# Angular 2 http request url is being changed when deployed in a sub-directory

Tags: http, angular, url, https

I have a fairly simple, angular cli generated app that works fine locally and when deployed at the root of the web server.
When I deploy it to a sub folder, it works, but the http request url is changed from the absolute url specified (and so fails).

the site is at 
mysite.myserver.com/subfolder
the api server is at
api.myserver.com

Code snipped calling the api

```
console.log(`Using ${url} for authentication`);
const  x = this.http.post(url, …
```

Output at runtime is

> Using https:/api.myserver.com/v1/authentication for authentication
>
> https://mysite.myserver.com/api.myserver.com/v1/authentication 405
>   (Not Allowed)

so you can see that it is adding the root to the front of the api url.

I am building with

> ng build --base-href /subfolder/

and my index.html has

```
<base href = "/">
```

Is it doing this because bot api. and mysite. are on the same server? More importantly - is there anything I can do to avoid this issue (other than moving the APIs to another server?)

** UPDATE: It seems that this issue happens only if the site is under https - irrespective of whether it is in a sub folder...

Answer (score 0):

The clue was there- but it took us a few hours before it jumped out at us:

Using https:/api.myserver.com/v1/authentication for authentication

Only one slash after the https: